# How I yank a function in a java code using vim

Tags: java, vim, yank

Java has curly braces that encapsulate the entire class definition. So when using the parenthsis ({ or }) key in vim, it goes to the end of the class instead of going to the next blank line or the end of the function definition. So how can I yank entire function and comment as well? In another word, I can I jump to next blank line regardless of the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the problem, vim should match curly brackets, you can use shift-% to toggle your cursor position on matched brackets.
With that said, if I understand you correctly(and trying it out myself) you are getting everything under the function header when you yank with ya{.
Try this:
on the end { of the function header, use **ma** to mark the position to register a, then **%** to move down to the end of the method, then **y'a** to yank it all. This will grab the entire function.

Comment: So I did ma/{<CR>%y'a to yank both the comment and the function. This is fewer strokes than my suggestion and works better in all cases. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, I make gratuitous use of ma myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can yank the contents of a method while the cursor is in the method with `yi{`, in other words **y** ank **i** nner **{**

Comment: if i do ya{, vim yanks the curly braces for the function as well, but it still does not yank the function header. Also I was hoping to find a solution so that yanks the comment as well. There is no new line between the comment and the function. So inanother word, how can I move between blank lines when I am in a function?

Answer (score 0):

This is answer I came up with and I am not happy with it.
In my vimrc, I set tab to be 4 whitespaces.
So if I know that my function is separated by line that has 4 white spaces,
I can do

```
y/^\s\s\s\s$
```